# How can I use OOP classes in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oop

I need to know how I can use a class in angularjs.

A simple class like this:

```
function Person(name,age){
    this.name=name;
    this.age=age;
    this.getAge(){
       return age;
    };
    //etcetera
}
```

I am learning angular but I can't find an answer to this. I want to create Person instances
and use the name, age etc. in the view.

Please a simple solution because I am from a C# OOP background and don't know js frameworks. But I want to use the MVC pattern. Thanks!

Comment: I recommend using jsFiddle or plunker to post what you have understood and what code you have tried. Others can comment on it and help you if you post your fiddle or plunker.

Answer (score 1):

AngularJS is a framework that is written in and used through JavaScript. Although JavaScript has many object oriented features, it handles inheritance quite differently. This used to be confusing to me too until I read the excellent: [JavaScript: The Good Parts](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742) by Douglas Crockford. I suggest you read this, it's quite a brief book and points out differences in approach in a very clear and concise manner.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is almost right, you just need to change the function declaration a bit:

```
function Person(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;

    this.getAge = function () {

        return age;
    };
}
```

Then you can create an instance like this:

`var p = new Person("John", 26);`

And do a call like this:

`console.log(p.name + ' is ' + p.getAge() + ' years old');`

Here it is in [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sgp6qomy/).

In general, I highly recommend using [Typescript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/), it complements angularjs in an excellent way. It makes your project very scalable, and adds intellisense. You can declare interfaces, classes, etc.